Robot Framework + SauceLabs - desired_capabilities has been deprecated and removed
I run Robot Framework tests in SauceLabs. After last upgrade of Selenium I receive the error :
"desired_capabilities has been deprecated and removed. Please use options to configure browsers as per documentation."
I see that data format of Options structure is different and it doesn't look like Dictionary.
Also I already use Options parameter as add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors").
And previously I added a sauce_options to desired_caps.
Could you help me to combine these configurations in new Options format, please ?
${sauce_options}    Create Dictionary    name="${PLATFORM_NAME}:${BROWSER} - ${TEST_NAME}"     
    ...                                      tunnelName=XXX   
    ...                                      extendedDebugging=true    
    ...                                      tunnelOwner=XXX

&{desired_caps}=    Create Dictionary
IF     '${DEVICE}'=='desktop'
        Set To Dictionary    ${sauce_options}    screenResolution=${RESOLUTION}
        Set To Dictionary    ${desired_caps}    browserName=${BROWSER}   
        ...                                     browserVersion=${VERSION}   
        ...                                     platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}    
        ...                                     **sauce:options=${sauce_options}**
        ...                                     unhandledPromptBehavior=dismiss
ELSE    
        Set To Dictionary    ${desired_caps}    browserName=${BROWSER}
        ...                                     platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}   
        ...                                     **sauce:options=${sauce_options}**
        ...                                     appium:deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}
        ...                                     appium:deviceOrientation=portrait
        ...                                     appium:platformVersion=${VERSION}
        ...                                     appium:autoDismissAlerts=true
${automation_name}    Set Variable If    ${iphone}==${TRUE}       ${automation.name.ios}     ${automation.name.android}
Set To Dictionary    ${desired_caps}    appium:automationName=${automation_name}
....
# Next keyword
IF     '${DEVICE}'=='desktop'   
            # Desktop
       IF    '${BROWSER}'!='firefox' and '${BROWSER}'!='MicrosoftEdge'
                Open Browser    ${url}    ${BROWSER}    remote_url=${saucelabsUrl}    desired_capabilities=${desired_caps}
       ELSE '${BROWSER}'=='firefox'  
                Open Browser    ${url}    ${BROWSER}    remote_url=${saucelabsUrl}    desired_capabilities=${desired_caps}    options=add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
       END
       
ELSE    
      # Simulator
      Open Browser    ${url}    ${BROWSER}    remote_url=${saucelabsUrl}    desired_capabilities=${desired_caps}
END


I expect to run Open Browser Keyword on desktop and mobile depending on $DEVICE variable
